# Rotating vector based on the position of another vector?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Sorry for terrible picture but lets say we have a unit vector A and we have vectors B and C. So for vector B I would want to rotate in a positive direction because the vector is "above A" and for vector C i would want to rotate downwards. Is there an easy way of detecting which way to rotate?

Comment: The "positive" rotation is usually counter-clockwise, but that'd mean that both B and C would rotate counter-clockwise. Is your goal to have A "repel" both B and C ?

Answer (score 0):

The naïve approach would be to use the trig function `arctan` to calculate their current angles, then decide which way to rotate and at what speed to do so.

For example:

```
function rotateTowards(from, to, speed) {
  // τ is Tau, ~= 6.28318530718

  diff = to - from; // Find the angle delta
  if (diff < 0) diff += τ; // If the delta is out of the unit circle, wrap it back in.
  if (abs(diff) < speed) return to; // We're within speed of our target, return target.

  if (diff < 0) newAngle = from - speed;
  newAngle = from + speed;

  // Make sure our new angle is still valid.
  if (newAngle > τ) newAngle -= τ;
  if (newAngle < 0) newAngle += τ;

  return newAngle;
}

// Declare our vectors.
A = new Vector(-1, -0.5);
B = new Vector(-2, -3);
//C = new Vector(-1, -2.5); Not using C, but it's here for completeness.

// Calculate each vector's angle using atan2
angle_a = atan2(a.y, a.x);
angle_b = atan2(b.x, b.y);
//angle_c = atan2(c.x, c.y); Same as above.

// Calculate A's magnitude
magnitude = sqrt(A.x ^ 2 + A.y ^ 2);
// Use our rotate function to adjust A's rotation
angle_a = rotateTowards(angle_a, angle_b, 0.01);

// Set A's x/y as per the new angle and old magnitude
A.x = cos(angle_a) * magnitude;
A.y = sin(angle_a) * magnitude;
```

In the above example the vector would rotate 0.01 radians per execution, but in practice you'd want to use something like `rpm * 60 * dt` where `dt` is your delta time in seconds.